# Istio rate limiting requirements

Tags: istio

I've been trying to test rate limiting between two services inside an Istio mesh.

Service A is a load generator which talks to service B, a simple http server. I'm trying to get Istio to limit the number of requests sent to the service B (the server).

I've defined the required `memquota`, `quota`, `rule`, `quotaSpec` and `quotaSpecBinding` resources as outlined in the Istio docs and applied them to the cluster.

Since the focus is to test rate limiting between two services "inside the mesh" service B is not accessible from outside the cluster (no `ingress` and `ingressgateway` defined). What I'm wondering is, if a `gateway`, `destinationRule` and a `virtualservice` is required for rate limiting to work in this case?

So far I've had no luck by applying the following configuration:

```
apiVersion: "config.istio.io/v1alpha2"
kind: memquota
metadata:
  name: handler
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  quotas:
  - name: requestcount.quota.istio-system
    maxAmount: 500
    validDuration: 1s
    overrides:
    - dimensions:
        destination: server
        source: loadgen
      maxAmount: 1
      validDuration: 5s

---
apiVersion: "config.istio.io/v1alpha2"
kind: quota
metadata:
  name: requestcount
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  dimensions:
    source: source.labels["app"] | source.service | "unknown"
    destination: destination.labels["app"] | destination.service | "unknown"

---
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: rule
metadata:
  name: quota
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  actions:
  - handler: handler.memquota
    instances:
    - requestcount.quota

---
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: QuotaSpec
metadata:
  name: request-count
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - quotas:
    - charge: 1
      quota: requestcount.quota.istio-system

---
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: QuotaSpecBinding
metadata:
  name: request-count
  namespace: default
spec:
  quotaSpecs:
  - name: request-count
    namespace: default
  services:
  - name: server
    namespace: default
```

I've been observing http request metrics and looking for rate changes when the rate limiting configuration is in place but see no noticeable difference before and after...

Any suggestions or help getting this working would be really appreciated!

Comment: Were u able to make this work?